# MySQL display columns from two tables without repeatation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables:

1. restaurants:

   ```
    Restaurant_ID | Restaurant_Name | Phone_1
   ```
2. menu:

   ```
   Item_ID | Rest_ID | Item_Name | Item_price
   ```

I want output:

```
Restaurant_ID| Item_Name | Item_price
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT  r.Restaurant_ID,
        m.Item_Name,
        m.Item_price 
FROM    restaurants r, menu m
WHERE   r.Restaurant_ID = (SELECT `Rest_ID` FROM menu WHERE Item_ID=1) LIMIT 0,1;
```

But output of this query is all rows from both the tables.
Actually i don't want to display all rows that's why i used LIMIT but i'm not getting desire output.

Comment: Assuming `Rest_ID` references  `restaurants.Restaurant_ID` a simple `SELECT Rest_ID AS Restaurant_ID, Item_Name, Item_Price from menu` would do. But I suppose you meant you wanted `Restaurant_Name | Item_Name | Item_price`?

Comment: Yes i want to displayRestaurant_ID| Item_Name | Item_price

Comment: Please show some sample input and the desired results. It's not clear what you're trying to do that's different from the answers that were posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.Restaurant_ID, m.Item_Name, m.Item_price
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN menu m ON r.Restaurant_ID=m.Rest_ID
WHERE Item_ID=1
```

Comment: Doesn't this query simply come down to `SELECT Rest_ID Restaurant_ID, Item_Name, Item_price FROM menu WHERE Item_ID=1`?

Comment: @Kenney Yes, in its current state, it does. However, we don't know what the OP wants to do with it. The fields in his question are just examples. I'm sure the real tables have much more fields, and he probably wants to include them in the query. My answer gives him exactly what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This will Get you the desired result

```
SELECT  r.Restaurant_ID,
        m.Item_Name,
        m.Item_price 
FROM    restaurants r
        JOIN (  SELECT Item_ID, Rest_ID, Item_Name, Item_price
                FROM Menu
                GROUP BY Item_ID, Rest_ID, Item_Name, Item_price) m
            ON r.Restaurant_ID = m.Rest_ID
WHERE   m.Item_Id = 1
```

Comment: I tried this query but output of this query is all rows from both the columns. I just want to display one row for each item

Comment: Alright @Littletilli, I've changed my query. This will give you one row per Item name and price for a restaurant.

Comment: Unless there's duplicates of `Item_ID+Rest_ID+Item_Name+Item_Price` in the `Menu` table, this will give the same results as just joining with `Menu`.

Comment: @Littletilli If you just want to display one row for each item, why are you selecting from the `Restaurants` table?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to change in your original query is the way you join the tables: `FROM menu m LEFT JOIN restaurants r ON ...`. Right now your query doesn't relate the two tables.

```
SELECT r.Restaurant_ID,m.Item_Name,m.Item_price
FROM menu m
LEFT JOIN restaurants r ON m.Rest_ID = r.Restaurant_ID
WHERE r.Restaurant_ID=(SELECT `Rest_ID` FROM menu WHERE Item_ID=1)
```

Comment: This is right query but i want output for particular rest_ID from menu.

Comment: @Littletilli I gave you the answer 53 minutes ago. Have you checked it? It seems you've checked all answers except mine :-)